# How to remove an object from the ActiveRecord::Relation object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am loading data from the DB and get it back in this object:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<CarStatusDefinition id: 10, status_name: "New Approval", keyword: 'NEW', ...>, #<CarStatusDefinition id: 11, status_name: "Used", keyword: 'USED', ...>, ...]>
```

When I have this data loaded in ruby, then, in some cases, I need to remove an item in this object - specifically, the one with the keyword **USED**.

I tried to do it like this:

```
if @record.used.blank?
  status_collection = status_collection.reject! { |hash| hash[:keyword] == 'USED' }
end
```

However, the item with the keyword **USED** (with `id 11` is still included in the final object).

How do I remove the object with id `11` from the final hash? What am I overlooking here?

Comment: You wan't to permanently remove it or just temporarilly for that particular action? I think you are having that problem because you are asigning the objects to the association. Can you show your use case for this? maybe you can use something better like a  named scope instead of that.

Answer (score 2):

`CarStatusDefinition.where.not(keyword: "USED")` will filter out all the CarStatusDefinition with keyword USED

Comment: I am familiar with this approach, where I can filter out the unwanted items straight on the AR level... however, I need to fetch all statuses and then, on the Ruby level, filter out the unwanted ones...

Comment: `status_collection = status_collection.select { |car_stat| car_stat.keyword != 'USED' }`

Comment: You could go with `reject` instead of using `select` and `!=`.